# How to deploy a war Java web application in Wamp server?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, war, wampserver

I have a web application which I developed in J2EE. I created my war file,deployed it correctly on Apache server and works as expected.

Now I need to make my application run on wamp server. I know that wamp is not for java j2ee application, but Is there a way to deploy my application on wamp? I thought about adding a php software layer : an index.php file executing the j2ee war like this:

```
<?php
shell_exec("java -war C:\wamp64\www\MyApp\webApp.war ");
?>
```

But it did not work, I have a white empty page.

What is wrong with my idea? How can I make my j2ee application run on a wamp server without the need of a Tomcat server?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you, but I've already checked that post, and it did not help me. It suggests to use both wamp ana Tomcat, while I need to use only Wamp server

Comment: What is that war suppose to do? If it is a web app, you _do_ need a server/container that can talk directly to your java app which WAMP isn't designed for... Why can't you install Tomcat or something next to WAMP?

Comment: war file contains the whole structure of my web application, with jsp and servlet files. Now I see the need of deploying it on a Tomcat... Thanks!

Comment: Put the war file in the "Tomcat/webapps" directory.